# Автоматически подставить категории в название товара, при его создании в WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

На cайте, который сейчас разрабатываю на WooCommerce, ссылки на товар отображаются следующим образом:

```
https://example.com/handles/roset/pasini/0031-cr-sat
```

Подскажите, как я могу автоматически подставить эти категории к названию продукта при его создании?

Например, если я напишу название продукта `0031 CR SAT`, в результате должно получится `Handles Roset Pasini 0031 CR SAT`. Как это сделать?

Никак не могу найти подходящий код и ответ на свой вопрос. Даже не знаю, с чего начать, поэтому в моем вопросе нет исходного кода.

Буду рад если поможете!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используем хук [save_post_(post_type)](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/save_post_-post_type)

```php
add_filter( 'save_post_product' , 'ruso1222520_modify_post_title' );
function ruso1222520_modify_post_title( $post_id, $post_data ) {
    // Получим оригинал заголовка
    $orig_title = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'original_title', 'true' );

    // Формируем новый заголовок из списка категорий товара
    // (список в виде ссылок, мы просто убираем html-теги)
    if (isset($orig_title) && !empty($orig_title)) {
        $new_title = wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_term_list( $post_id, 'product_cat', '', '', '')) . ' ' . $orig_title;
        // Запишем заголовок
        wp_update_post( [
            'ID'         => $post_id,
            'post_title' => $new_title,
        ] );
    } else {
        // Запишем оригинал в мета-поле, если его нет
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'original_title', $post_data->post_title );
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Только в этом случае, при создании товара, категории не добавляются. А если редактировать товар и менять категорию, добавляется старая категория. Есть возможность перед редактированием, чистить старые данные?

Comment: @Dmitry возможность есть, это 100%. Думаю, тогда на хуке `wp_insert_post_data` нужно записывать "оригинал" заголовка в кастомное поле, и генерировать новый заголовок из "оригинала" и новых данных хуком `save_post`, по тому же принципу

Comment: Я понял. Займусь этим. Еще раз спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Если не получится - пишите, я отредактирую ответ. Пожалуйста :)

Comment: @malginovdesign в любом случае стоит отредактировать ответ. SO - это же FAQ-сервис. Другим будет полезно.